# How to run external jar functions in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created a jar package from a project by this file-tree:

```
build.sbt
src/main
src/main/scala
src/main/scala/Tester.scala
src/main/scala/main.scala
```

where Tester is a class by a function (name is print()) and main has an object to run that prints "Hi!" (from spark documention)
created a jar file by sbt successfully and worked well in spark-submit

now I wanna add it into spark-shell and use Tester class as a class to create objects and ...
I added the jar file into spark-default.conf but:

```
scala> val t = new Tester();
<console>:23: error: not found: type Tester
       val t = new Tester();
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

you can try by providing jars with argument as below

```
./spark-shell --jars pathOfjarsWithCommaSeprated
```

Or you can add following configuration in you spark-defaults.conf but remember to remove template from end of spark-defaults

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath  pathOfJarsWithCommaSeprated
```

Comment: i did it but now how can i use Tester class?

Answer (score 43):

If you want to add a .jar to the classpath after you've entered spark-shell, use `:require`. Like:

```
scala> :require /path/to/file.jar
Added '/path/to/file.jar' to classpath.
```

Comment: I tried to `:require` the jar but got error like: *The path '/export/home/xxx.jar' cannot be loaded, because existing classpath entries conflict.* how can I find out which is causing the conflict ? thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to forcefully include jar removing the existing one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried two options and both worked for me.

1. `spark-shell --jars <path of jar>`
2. open spark-shell    -Type :help,you will get all the available help.
   use below to add

   :require /full_path_of_jar

[image]